# How to fire parent function on change when something happens in child without touching the child component

Tags: angular

So I have this child component which I wish I don't want to disturb, this component has a `<ng-select>` in it. I want the the parent component to detect if there is any changes made to this child component. So it looks like this now:

**Parent-component.html**

```
<div>
 <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

I have a function in the ts file if there is a change happening like this:

**Parent-component.ts**

```
changeFunction() {
 ***something happens***
}
```

I initially just tried adding a `(change)=changeFunction()` to the child component, making it like this:

```
<div>
 <child-component (change)=changeFunction()></child-component>
</div>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there anything I could do to detect when a change is made in the child component without having to do anything on the child component itself?

Comment: No, you will have to modify your child component, no way around it. Child component need to emit an event or via some sort of state management.

Comment: No real way to do anything useful or elegant without binding through Input of emitting through Output, or using services/subjects. That being said, if you want to access elements of child component (if you parse DOM for classes, tags, id's...) and check their values for changes, you *could* use ngDoCheck() in parent for that. However, it will fire more often than you'd like, so you'd need some additional logic to make sure you're catching the real (expected) changes, like introducing vars to keep initial values and checking new values against them.